# How can I get the MAX COUNT for multiple users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I'm sorry if this happens to be a re-post however looking through all of the previous questions I could find with similar wording I have not been able to find a working answer.

I have a `trainingHistory` table that has a record for every new training.  The training can be done by multiple `trainers`.  `Clients` can have multiple `trainers`.

What I am trying to accomplish is to `COUNT` the number of `clients` that was **last** trained by each `trainer`.

Example:

```
clientID | trainDate          | trainerID
101      | 2012-03-13 10:58:11| 10
101      | 2012-03-12 10:58:11| 11
102      | 2012-03-15 10:58:11| 10
102      | 2012-03-09 10:58:11| 12
103      | 2012-03-08 10:58:11| 7
```

So the end result I am looking for would be:

```
Results
trainerID | count
10        | 2
7         | 1
```

I've tried quite a few different queries and looked over quite a few answers, including this one here [Using sub-queries in SQL to find max(count())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740563/using-sub-queries-in-sql-to-find-maxcount) but have so far been unable to get the desired result.

What I keep getting is like this:

```
Results
trainerID | count
10        | 5
7         | 5
```

How can I get an accurate `count` per `trainer` as opposed to an overall total?

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
SELECT      t.trainerName,
            t.trainerID,
            (
                SELECT      COUNT(lastTrainerCount)
                FROM        (
                                SELECT      MAX(th.clientID) AS lastTrainerCount
                                FROM        trainingHistory th
                                GROUP BY    th.clientID
                            )   AS lastTrainerCount
            )
FROM        trainers t
INNER JOIN  trainingHistory th ON (th.trainerID = t.trainerID)
WHERE       th.trainingDate BETWEEN '12/14/14' AND '02/07/15'
GROUP BY    t.trainerName, t.trainerID
```

Which results in:

```
Results
trainerID | count
10        | 1072
7         | 1072
```

Using **SQL Server 2012**

Appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the max `trainDate` per `clientID` in `sub-select`. Then `count` the `trainerID` in outer query.  Try this.

```
select trainerID,count(trainerID) [Count]
From
(
select clientID,trainDate,trainerID,
       row_number()over(partition by clientID order by trainDate Desc) Rn
From yourtable
) A
where Rn=1
Group by trainerID
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b23c/1)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm getting the following error: Incorrect syntax near 'A'

Comment: That appears to have done it, gonna need to do some research on this one to find out what is going on here but definitely appreciate the quick response!  Thanks!